# How to open a java source tree in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, java

There is a directory tree with java sources here and there like src\com\company\foo\etc. I am trying to build and debug this luxury with Netbeans. I tried to create a new project and replace the template files with real ones but I cannot achieve the same directory structure this way. There is option of Eclipse project import but this is not an eclipse project. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new project from existing source code.  Select
 **"File" --> "New Project" --> "Categories:" --> "Java" --> "Java Project with Existing Sources"** then browse for the existing src directory as well as test directory (if one exists).

Answer (score 0):

Create new empty java project, and copy contents of your "src" dir to /src in project directory. If the structure of folders is the same as packages (it should be like this), then everything will be just fine.